# GUI to control multiple remote hosts (using the same GUI for simulation and real hardware)

Tags: python, ssh, virtualization, simulation

I've a GUI based on python and gtk, my program manages varios applications in the same machine using subprocesses, i.e a button launchs an emulated host, another button connects it to a switch ...  now I want to but each component in a separated machine (some hosts will work as soft switches, others may work as routers...)

I may link GUI to machines by sockets, xml, spawning ssh subprocess or using telnet, I also find that [fabric](http://fabfile.org) may be cleaner than handmade ssh sessions.

Q: What is the easiest, most robust technology to use? I don't mind installing any client on the controlled machines.

Answers based on similar experiance would be great, but also any suggestion would be helpful. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a mechanism that works to spawn the processes on the local machine, it sounds like the only thing you're lacking is a way to spawn the processes on the remote machines.  I would go with simple ssh connections as it would require the fewest changes to both your infrastructure and your code.

Comment: I agree that it seems to be the most straight forward solution, however, it is too low level, and in the future I may need to add more complex interaction,so I want to be sure I'm doing a good choice from the beginning. thanks